# Postgresql insert trigger to concatenate

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I want to create a trigger to concatenate my column with event "before insert", but the query didn't work and i got an error:

> SQL error:
>
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SET" LINE 4: SET new.fullname =
>   CONCAT(new.first_name, '', new.mid_name, ...

```
In statement:
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON t_employees
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.fullname = CONCAT(new.first_name, '', new.mid_name, '', new.last_name);
```

Comment: Postgres doesn't really have triggers.  I mean, it does have `create trigger`, but this is just used to execute a procedure (which is really a function).  Your syntax looks more like MySQL.

Comment: Yep, its MySQL syntax. I think it can be used in Postgresql but it doesn't. I've tried to made an insert trigger with same event from phpPgAdmin but still didn't work. Would you help me please how to create a trigger in Postgresql ?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE

Answer (score 4):

Here's a working solution:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_employees (
    first_name TEXT,
    mid_name TEXT,
    last_name TEXT,
    fullname TEXT
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_fullname()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        NEW.fullname = NEW.first_name || ' ' || NEW.mid_name || ' ' || NEW.last_name;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$ language 'plpgsql';


CREATE TRIGGER set_fullname_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON t_employees
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_fullname();


SET client_min_messages TO 'debug';
INSERT INTO t_employees VALUES ('fname1', 'mname1', 'lname1');
SELECT * FROM t_employees;
UPDATE t_employees SET first_name = 'updated-first-name';
SELECT * FROM t_employees;
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, i finally did it. According your suggestions and postgresql docs i've made the trigger like what i want. Here is the syntax:

**create the function:**

```
 CREATE FUNCTION insert_funct() RETURN TRIGGER AS 
    $$
    BEGIN
      SELECT new.fullname := CONCAT(new.first_name, '', new.mid_name, '', new.last_name);
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

then **create the trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON t_employees
  FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_funct();
```

Comment: Your trigger function is wrong. It will set the fullname for **all** rows to the one of the currently inserted one. Plus: the `update` is not needed in the first place. Use `new.fullname := concat(...)`

Comment: Still wrong. You do **not** need `update` at all. A single line with `new.fullname := concat(...);` is all you need. See the examples in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE

Comment: Well ya I've decided not to use a trigger, and using select query "concat" to combine it on one column. I think its much better than use a trigger.