# Concatenate 3 Columns into 1 Column automatically Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, concatenation

```
Columns:
FirstName 
MiddleName 
LastName
```

I want to automatically concatenate into a 4th column called 'FullName' separated by spaces Every time data is entered or changed in one of the above 3 columns the 'FullName' column is updated.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMogy.png)

Comment: see this [thread so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568071/postgresql-insert-trigger-to-concatenate)

Answer (score 1):

Postgres doesn't support( as of Version 11 ) a Virtual column / derived column.

You may create a View instead.

```
CREATE OR replace VIEW v_names 
AS 
  SELECT firstname, 
         middlename, 
         lastname, 
         firstname 
         ||CASE 
             WHEN nullif(middlename, '') IS NULL THEN '' 
             ELSE ' ' 
                  ||middlename 
           END 
         ||CASE 
             WHEN nullif(lastname, '')   IS NULL THEN '' 
             ELSE ' ' 
                  ||lastname 
           END AS FullName 
  FROM   names;
```

---

```
knayak=# INSERT INTO names(FirstName,MiddleName,LastName) VALUES ( 'John', 'Maynard','Keynes');
INSERT 0 1
knayak=# INSERT INTO names(FirstName,MiddleName,LastName) VALUES ( 'John','','Doe');
INSERT 0 1

knayak=# select * from v_names;
 firstname | middlename | lastname |      fullname
-----------+------------+----------+---------------------
 John      | Maynard    | Keynes   | John Maynard Keynes
 John      |            | Doe      | John Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

giving a mysql answer since you left a mysql tag:

In MySQL you can create a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html), using the [CONCAT_WS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) function.